# Report/Query to find all "Service Cloud User" in the system

Tags: reporting, query, servicecloud

We currently have Service Cloud User license. How can I run a report/query (whatever it is) to find all the users with **Service Cloud User** permission?
This field doesn't seem to be available. It's quite annoying as we are losing count/control of who should have this permission.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer should help you out. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23413/how-to-query-all-user-with-salesforce-license just substitute the license type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a report I found this suggestion from a PM on the idea posted [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqGHAA0)...

> For internal license usage, edit a report type based on Users and in
>   the page layout, add a field lookup following this path:
>   User=>Profile=>User License; from there you have access to "Total
>   Licenses" and "User License ID". In your report add a filter on the
>   user license ID and it will return all the users in this license.

Update based on comment: From the help [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jBbfAAE) they suggest doing an export and point to another idea here.

> Resolution
>
> As there is currently no option to create a report on a list of
>   Service Cloud Users.
>
> The current work around is to use the Apex Data Loader to export a
>   list of users (with) or (with and without) the "Service Cloud User"
>   option enabled.
>
> The field on the user object which holds the "Service Cloud User"
>   checkbox value is "USERPERMISSIONSSUPPORTUSER". Using the data loader,
>   we can export a list of users with service cloud user checkbox enabled
>   by adding a filter USERPERMISSIONSSUPPORTUSER=TRUE
>
> This Column / Field does not show up when you are using the Data
>   Export Services.  So Apex Data Loader is the only workaround as of
>   now.
>
> Vote for the current Idea in the Idea Exchange if you would like for
>   this to be reviewed and possibly implemented by clicking the link
>   below:

You can query for this field as well, tested in the developer console

```
Select USERPERMISSIONSSUPPORTUSER from user
```

Comment: Thank you but not quite what I'm looking for because Service Cloud User is a feature license, not a license. Right?

Comment: @brovasi gotcha, updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Jenny, help a lot. Not really obvious that the api name of Service Cloud User is SupportUser. I which it would be available via formula field.