# How to query users group by licences?

Tags: permission-sets, licenses, userlicense, user-profile

I need to get users list which is group by the Salesforce licence. I need to get Permission set licences as well. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: please have a look at [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23413/how-to-query-all-user-with-salesforce-license), looks similar to your.

Comment: Also refer `PermissionSetLicenseAssign` and `PermissionSetLicense` sobjects

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the users based on the License type, please refer the below code to collect a map of LicenseId to List of Users (can collect based on License Name as well).

```
Map<String, List<User>> mapLicenseToLstUser = new Map<String, List<User>>();
Map<Id, List<User>> mapLicenseIdToLstUser = new Map<Id, List<User>>();

for(User objUser : [select Id, Profile.UserLicense.Name From User Where Profile.UserLicenseId != null]) {
  if(!mapLicenseToLstUser.containsKey(objUser.Profile.UserLicense.Name)) {
    mapLicenseToLstUser.put(objUser.Profile.UserLicense.Name, new List<User>());
  }
  mapLicenseToLstUser.get(objUser.Profile.UserLicense.Name).add(objUser);

  if(!mapLicenseIdToLstUser.containsKey(objUser.Profile.UserLicenseId)) {
    mapLicenseIdToLstUser.put(objUser.Profile.UserLicenseId, new List<User>());
  }
  mapLicenseIdToLstUser.get(objUser.Profile.UserLicenseId).add(objUser);
}
system.debug('=======mapLicenseToLstUser======'+mapLicenseToLstUser);
system.debug('=======mapLicenseIdToLstUser======'+mapLicenseIdToLstUser);
```

[image]